# Constructor a of base class has more parameters than constructor of derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, googletest

To use gtest to test class myPRTlsConnectionImpl which has 2 parameters in its default constructor. I plan to use another class called TestMyPRTlsConnectionImpl:

```
class TestMyPRTlsConnectionImpl: public testing::Test, public mySaiPRTlsConnectionImpl {
     .......
}
```

To use this class as a test fixture, I want its default constructor has no parameter. Can I do the following things?

```
class TestMyPRTlsConnectionImpl: public testing::Test, public 
mySaiPRTlsConnectionImpl {
   int a;
   int b;

   TestMyPRTlsConnectionImpl: mySaiPRTlsConnectionImpl(a, b),
                             a(5), b(6) {
         ........
   }
}
```

1. Is that possible base class has more paramters?
2. Is the order od `a(5), b(6)` and `mySaiPRTlsConnectionImpl(a, b)` important here?

Comment: `TestMyPRTlsConnectionImpl:` is malformed. Supply a compilable piece of code and you will get much more help. If you can't get it to compile do the best you can and supply the code and error messages. Also, the order of declarations in the class, not the initializers, determines construction sequence but inherited classes get initialized first.

Comment: Thank you! The reason why I put ` a(5), b(6)`  before `mySaiPRTlsConnectionImpl(a, b) ` is that I think the constructor of the base class need the value of a and b..... I just modified them.